# Bitlocker Powershell Module

Tags: bitlocker

I'm newer to the topic of Powershell modules in general, finding them, downloading (or finding/installing them from the internet using find-module and install-module, etc.). But I specifically need information at the moment about finding/installing the bitlocker module. I see numerous forum references to the cmdlets in this module but no one mentions the module itself. 'Install-module bitlocker' errors out with 'No match was found' for that module name. I'm doing this from a Windows 2016 server.

Answer (score 0):

[Poweshell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/) doesnt show any exact match for a Bitlocker module for being installed using `install-module`, instead it show some related utilities, this is because Bitlocker module is [included in ps itself](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/?view=win10-ps).

So, if you need to enable Bitlocker from powershell you should use `Enable-bitlocker` [cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/enable-bitlocker?view=win10-ps)